Rarely but right on target
Is there a phrase or idiom to describe something that happens rarely but it's always spot on?
Would you say?:

rarely but right on target
He speaks rarely but right on target (implying that speaks only right things)


He speaks rarely but, when he does, he is right on target.

An idiomatic expression for someone who rarely speaks is a person of few words (historically, a man of few words). This usually implies that a person speaks only when necessary, so could also imply that what they do say is helpful. It doesn't simply mean shy or quiet, but it may not fully convey the impact of the words spoken that you want.
After a bit of Googling I found that the phrase "a man of few words, but full of wisdom" occurs quite often in different places. This seems to be a combination of two different idioms and probably describes what you want to say.
